# theories/research on the suffix 'ish'

Tags: meaning

Can anyone tell me if there is any research/theories/books that can tell me more about the suffix 'ish'? I am looking for any information regarding the usage of the suffix and how it was formed? Any help :) thank you! much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ish is a very flexible-ish suffix that is used to form
nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and slang.

Origin:
From Old English (-isc); Old Norse (-iskr); to Greek (-iskos).

As nouns:
to show nationality: Turkish;
to show language: English;
to show profession: dervish

Verbs:
cherish; flourish

Adjectives:
to show like, as in "They met at five-ish."
to show something has characteristics like, as in "She is a boyish girl."
to show something that tends toward, as in "He is bookish."

Adverbs:
as in regularly-ish: "He leaves regularly-ish."

Used in slang:

A: Are you sleepy?
B: Yea, ish!

Also, if you like, please check out this link:
http://web.mit.edu/ayakasug/www/Sugawara2012ish.pdf

Hope that helps.

Comment: Similarity between this and @user99577's answer seems to require explanation. Perhaps this was intended as an edit rather than a separate answer. Both even make the same mistake of classifying the informal stand-alone usage as nominal.

Comment: Also, for synonym for either usage I would suggest *somewhat,* in the sense that OED classifies as *adv.*

Comment: would you say 'ish' nowadays is being used to convey approximation? e.g. 11ish or laterish?

Comment: @zarakhan, yes, certainly, in the former case, but not I think in the latter.

Comment: ok thank you @BrianDonovan so if someone was to say 'it's your turn next ish' what would 'ish' be classified as there?

Comment: @zarakhan, here in Minnesota I would interpret that 'ish' as an interjection expressing distaste (at the prospect of serving me, or at the service I was likely to receive); no other parsing of that particular usage would really begin to make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it can be used as a suffix meaning "like" (he is tallish), but in other cases it is used as an actual word. For example,

A: Are you sleepy?
B: Yea, ish.

In sum, it is a suffix coming from Old English (-isc); and of Germanic origin,
even Greek (-iskos). However, it is now also used as a noun (informally, of course,) in the States.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your help :) is there any evidence to suggest that 'ish' can stand alone? or how 'ish' came about to be an actual word?

Comment: Yes, ish can stand alone. Please see the link I sent. I also wrote more info, but it was somehow deleted.